# Selecting one selectbox blanks other select box

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

I have two select boxes in which 1st one is having names of Units and second one has names of chapters. My problem is whenever I am selecting option in the  first select box option i.e. Units, my second drop down i.e. Chapters becomes empty. While doing reverse, i.e. if I am selecting the chapters first and then Unit, again the chapters becomes blank.
What could be the possible reason behind it? Here is my code,

```
 function selectBoxsearch($tableName, $field1, $field2, $value)
{   

    echo "<option value=''>--Select--</option>";
    $sq=mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM $tableName where status=1 order by id ASC");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sq))
        {
            if($value==$row[$field1])
            {

        echo "<option value='$row[$field1]' selected='selected'; >$row[$field2]</option>";  
            }
            else
            {

        echo "<option value='$row[$field1]' >$row[$field2]</option>";   
            }
        }                   

}  



 <div class="form-group">
 <div class="col-md-12">
 <div class="col-md-3">
 <label for="username" class="control-label">Select Unit:</label>
</div>
<div class="col-md-9">
<select name="unit_id" class="form-control"  required="" id="unit_id">
 <?php $fnc->selectBoxsearch("tbl_question_module","id","title", $unit_id) ; ?>
</select>
</div>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <div class="col-md-12">
 <div class="col-md-3">
<label for="username" class="control-label">Select Chapter:</label>
   </div>
  <div class="col-md-9">
  <select name="chapter" class="form-control" required id="chapter_id" >   

<option value="">Select</option>                  
<?php 

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id, title FROM tbl_studymaterials where status =1 ");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){   
$chapter = $row['title'];

echo "<option value=" . $row['id'] . ">" . $chapter . "</option>";
    }

    ?>
</select>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: is there some javascript assigned as an event handler to one or both select menus? Does the page reload when one or other select menu is changed? What does `selectBoxsearch` do?

Comment: You must provide what the php variable $fnc represents, and what function selectBoxSearch does. If you are unaware what this function does for whatever reason, I'm guessing it populates the selects with values found, which is where the problem may lie.

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[this happens](https://media.giphy.com/media/kg9t6wEQKV7u8/giphy.gif)**
 it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.0+.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: @RamRaider Luckily that seems to work. I have not used that comment very often lately, when I used to use it 10 times a day, so maybe its encouraging people to stop using `the mysql_` extension :)

Comment: Quite simply, when you reload the page with the contents of the OTHER dropdown, you have to check the selecting dropdown for its contents and replace it in its dropdown. Or set `selected` on the `<option>` tag containing that value

Comment: @RamRaider No there are no event handler. And I have edited my question for  selectBoxsearch

Comment: @RiggsFolly Can you point out where and what are you mentioning

Comment: Was looking for some meaningful and sensible advice for this prob, but can't find any other than some animated timepass GIF's.

Comment: @Ansh it was a comical attempt at telling you that mysql_* is deprecated and should be avoided. The alternatives are PDO and mysqli_*. Deprecated means subject for removal, if it hasn't been already. mysql_* has been removed entirely as of PHP7.0+ as he pointed out. Therefore, if you are just starting, it would be beneficial for you to change your database notation to either PDO or mysqli_ as it is what should be used these days. :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the solution. I was passing wrong id to the Chapter label . So it should be `id= chapter` but not `id= chapter_id`. Thanks